# How to control form from script in .net scripting

Tags: c#, python, .net, winforms, python.net

I am using pythonnet for scripting winforms.

```
class IForm(Form):
    def __init__(self):
        self.excel_file = None
        self.Text = 'Demo'
        self.Size = Size(250, 200)
        self.Icon = Icon(icon)
        self.label = Label()
        self.label.Location = Point(0, 130)
        self.label.Name = "label1"
        self.label.Size = Size(110, 15)
        self.label.TabIndex = 2
        self.label.Text = "© 2016"
        _font = Font("Serif", 7.0)
        self.label.Font = _font
        self.label.ForeColor = Color.Gray
        self.label.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left)
        self.Controls.Add(self.label)
        self.sb = StatusBar()
        self.sb.Parent = self
        self.CenterToScreen()

def workingscript(data_dict):
    guiform = IForm()
    Application.Run(guiform)
    guiform.sb.Text = "Working" #not working
    Application.Close(guiform) #not working
```

Everything works fine except I don't know how to control the application from withing script after it initialize.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/tree/master/demo

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "to control"? Give some examples

Comment: For example if I want to change the statusbar.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to call the .Refresh() method?

Comment: Look at the demos that I linked, you need to set the STA threading correctly

Comment: And Where do i add .Refresh() method?